# SOLR OR Query Strangeness

Tags: solr, sunspot

I'm running an `OR` keyword search in SOLR but the result set is smaller than running a keyword search for only one of the words (as if it's doing an `AND` instead). Here is the query:

```
path=select parameters={fq: ["type:Product"], q: "iphone OR android", fl: "* score", qf: "name_textp description_text", defType: "edismax", start: 0, rows: 30}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there anything I need to modify in the config?

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using? There [was an issue with q.op=AND having precedence over boolean operators](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8812). Try appending `q.op=OR` to your query (and run it directly in Solr when debugging instead of through sunspot).

Comment: you ever figured this out?